# WebSphere - Jython command to view an Application's memory usage

Tags: websphere, jmx, heapspace

Using IBM WebSphere Application Server version 8.0.0.1, is there a way to view the memory usage of a running application on the server? Something with Jython or Jacl? I can view the memory usage of a Application Server, but not the individual applications themselves.

Answer (score 1):

All applications share the JVM heap. There is no clear delineation of which application is using which.

You could force a heap dump and use some of the IBM diagnostic tooling to look at the output and try to manually determine which objects belong to which application, but even that will be confused by shared objects.